# Is it possible using t-sql, to create a stored procedure where you query a remote database using an ODBC data-source in the stored procedure?

Tags: t-sql

Is it possible, using t-sql,  to create a stored procedure where you query a remote database using an ODBC data-source in the stored procedure?

I have a server with an ODBC data-source.

I use via Power Bi successfully.  I would like to create a stored procedure to query the remote database using the stored procedure with the odbc data-source.

I have looked at opendatasource command, but it only uses OLE DB connections.

Thanks in advance for your time.
Dean-O

Comment: setup a linked server that uses the ODBC data source that you configured on the SQL server, then you can use the 4 part naming in your query, Linkedserver.database.schema.object... or you can also use the linked server via openquery().

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Search the following keywords: Linked servers, OpenQuery, OpenDataSource, OpenRowSet.

Comment: doesn't the remote server have to have something set up in their preferences to allow for a linking of a server?

Comment: No, you specify the credentials to use for queries to the linked server in the setup of the linked server on your server.

Comment: Thanks, we got it to work, had to use the ip address of the remote server but the rest of the info given above was correct.  from statements needed to include the linked_Server_Name dot DB_Name dot schema dot table_Name

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, Tim Mylott, we got it to work, had to use the ip address of the remote server but the rest of the info given above was correct. from statements needed to include the linked_Server_Name dot DB_Name dot schema dot table_Name